# Find a match on a line, and insert this result into each following line until it matches END

Tags: shell, awk, design-patterns, grep, match

I have a file similar to this

```
NAME : Name1
TYPE : Something2
TEST : Something3
END
NAME : Name2
TYPE : Something5
TEST : Something6
END
```

All the contents after the ':' are going to be different values

This repeats until the end of the file

I would like to create another file with the output looking like

```
NAME : Name1
Name1 TYPE : Something2
Name1 TEST : Something3
END
NAME : Name2
Name2 TYPE : Something5
Name2 TEST : Something6
END
```

Have tried

```
awk '/NAME/ {print;while($0!~ /END/){getline;print;}}' InputFile > OutputFile
```

but do not know how to get the Name matches to be inserted as it finds them.

I am using shell script

Any help much appreciated

Terry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
$1=="END"  { pfx = ""     }      # clear prefix
           { $1  = pfx $1 }      # append prefix to 1st field
$1=="NAME" { pfx = $NF " "}      # define prefix as last field + space
1                                # print current line
' InputFile
```

This generates:

```
NAME : Name1
Name1 TYPE : Something2
Name1 TEST : Something3
END
NAME : Name2
Name2 TYPE : Something5
Name2 TEST : Something6
END
```

Comment: I have tried it, and it works perfectly, I will have to study further to understand how, thank you so much for your quick response

Comment: I know you have answered very well the problem I gave but I realise there is more to it. in the returned 'Name1' i need to modify it so that a £ is included after the third char, is that possible.

Comment: is it possible? probably; would need to see an example but at this point you'd need to modify the question which in turn would negate the current set of answers; the recommended method is to take the answers you've received to this question, see if you can modify them to suit your new requirement and if you're unable to make the desired changes then ask a new question

Comment: Yes you are correct, however I have modified what you sent to achieve the required result, still a one liner quite chuffed, thanks again.
I will remember what you advised for future.

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk no matter which characters are in `Name<N>`, including spaces or `:`s:

```
$ awk '
    match($0,/^NAME[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*/) { name=substr($0,RLENGTH+1) }
    { print ( /^(NAME|END)/ ? "" : name " ") $0 }
' file
NAME : Name1
Name1 TYPE : Something2
Name1 TEST : Something3
END
NAME : Name2
Name2 TYPE : Something5
Name2 TEST : Something6
END
```

e.g. using this input with some more interesting names:

```
$ cat file
NAME : This Name
TYPE : Something2
TEST : Something3
END
NAME : That : Name
TYPE : Something5
TEST : Something6
END
```

```
$ awk '
    match($0,/^NAME[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*/) { name=substr($0,RLENGTH+1) }
    { print ( /^(NAME|END)/ ? "" : name " ") $0 }
' file
NAME : This Name
This Name TYPE : Something2
This Name TEST : Something3
END
NAME : That : Name
That : Name TYPE : Something5
That : Name TEST : Something6
END
```